# Removing adapters + primers from fastq files

Tags: fastq, linux, metagenome, qc, cutadapt

I am currently in the process of removing adapters and primers from some 16S data acquired, and have a conceptual question regarding this pre-processing step:

So there are a series of different primer sequences (4 for the forward and 4 for the reverse strands), as well as two adapter sequences (1 for each strand) overhanging these primers.

To test this process I am currently using `cutadapt`. Just to give you an example of what one of my primers vs. adapters look like:

`"ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGTGCCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA" -> fp`

`"ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCT" -> a1`

So my question is: Given that the adapters are overhanging these primers (a1 is a an exact match with first N base pairs in fp), could we just use `cutadapt` once, in order to remove the primers + adapter sequences in one go?